# /etc/localtime is messy code

Tags: 16.04, time

I want to disable utc in ubuntu 16.04

Someone said it can be done in `/etc/adjtime` but I cannot find this file,just found `/etc/localtime`.

However,after doing `vi /etc/localtime` it shows something strange like: `TZif2^@^@`  or    `^L<80>^@^@^@È\^A<80>Èú'pÉó^N`

What can I do to fix this?   And how can I disable utc now?

Comment: The file `/etc/localtime` is not a textfile and everything is fine with it. Could you post the output of `timedatectl`.

Comment: You are right.`timedatectl` outputs well,`/etc/localtime` is fine,I aimed at it mistakenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do to fix this?

I am not sure what you were expecting, but that is not code. It is timezone data.

```
~> file /etc/localtime 
/etc/localtime: symbolic link to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome
andrea@farore ~> file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome: symbolic link to San_Marino
andrea@farore ~> file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/San_Marino 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/San_Marino: timezone data, version 2, 7 gmt time flags, 7 std time flags, no leap seconds, 171 transition times, 7 abbreviation chars
```

If you want to change the timezone of your computer without using the nifty GUI that Ubuntu provides for this purpose, you can always overwrite the link. For example:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Madrid /etc/localtime
```

Comment: I'm truly sorry about my unclear expression.I have got what you mean,it's useful.Actually ,the beginning of my confusion is that I install both win10 and ubuntu16.04 in my computer,and this leads to the error of time.  It is said that win10 uses bios hardware time as system time,while ubuntu uses UTC,this will include the concept of timezone.Now I'm trying to disable UTC,    [link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=151027)  `/etc/adjtime` change UTC to LOCAL(I cannot find this file)  
`/etc/default/rcS` UTC=no(There is not such a line)  Neither of them works.

Comment: I think `timedatectl  set-local-rtc 1` should set the local BIOS clock to local time and also creates the needed files.

Comment: @Thomas  I tried just now,this will change the RTC time,but do nothing to Local time or Universal time,and the system shows the Local time.

Comment: I think you should read [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/).

Comment: Finally!   It synchronized the hardware time(RTC) with local time.I shoud restart my computer before.I never thought it could be so easy...